# swift display default username

Tags: xcode, swift

```
@IBOutlet weak var studyID: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var userID: UITextField!

let username: String = self.studyID.text!
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setObject(username, forKey: "username")
```

How am I able to store the username and display when next time I open this app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this in `viewDidAppear()`

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    username = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("username") as! String
    print(username)
}
```

make sure you save successfully.

```
let username: String = self.studyID.text!
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()    
defaults.setObject(username, forKey: "username")
defaults.synchronize()
```